# Display PHP object depending on day of the week

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I have the hours of a business set up in 7 different objects each for a day of the week. I wanted to be able to display in the header the hours of this business for the day that it currently is. Set it up like this but it won't spit anything out

```
<?php
    $d=date("D");
    if ($d=="Mon")
    echo <?php echo of_get_option('monday', 'no entry'); ?>;
    elseif ($d=="Tue")
    echo <?php echo of_get_option('tuesday', 'no entry'); ?>;
    elseif ($d=="Wed")
    echo <?php echo of_get_option('wednesday', 'no entry'); ?>;
    elseif ($d=="Thu")
    echo <?php echo of_get_option('thursday', 'no entry'); ?>;
    elseif ($d=="Fri")
    echo <?php echo of_get_option('friday', 'no entry'); ?>;
    elseif ($d=="Sat")
    echo <?php echo of_get_option('saturday', 'no entry'); ?>;
    elseif ($d=="Sun")
    echo <?php echo of_get_option('sunday', 'no entry'); ?>;
    else
    echo "Have a nice day!";
?>
```

Comment: What is with all the extra PHP tags? Aren't they unnecessary?

Comment: If you are referring to '<?php echo of_get_option('monday', 'no entry'); ?>' that is the object that holds the data the client inputs from the admin panel of wordpress.

Comment: @Davey I think you can remove the additional PHP tags and echos and leave your of_get_option functions, and it should output fine, assuming of_get_option returns a value to echo.

Comment: That would just display all the hours in a list.

Comment: @Davey Isn't that what you want? The hours corresponding to each day? If Monday, give me Monday hours? I must be confused about what `of_get_options` does.

Comment: Those are tags specific to the back end of a wordpress site. When the client puts their hours in through the admin panel those are the tags used to display them. They are the hours, I just need one at a time to show up corresbonding with the correct day.

Comment: You certainly don't need to open other PHP tags if one is already open.

Comment: @Davey I'm just trying to get clarification. So, of_get_options will return a string of several hours for one day? Can we see example output of that? You may consider formatting the result of that function, and fix those nested PHP tags. (So confused)

Comment: @bazmegakapa Indeed, that seems to have solved it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am assuming you don't have problems with the nested php tags, would be too obvious.

Since the conditions are correct, you should check the function of_get_option(). How does it work, does it return anything? Check with var_dump().

Furthermore it would be way cleaner to use

```
date("N")
```

so you get numbers from 1 to 7 for the weekdays.

edit: Ok, in reply to your comment, I think you copypasted these php-tag-parts from somewhere. So please try:

```
<?php
    $d=date("D");
    if ($d=="Mon")
      echo of_get_option('monday', 'no entry');
    elseif ($d=="Tue")
      echo of_get_option('tuesday', 'no entry');
    elseif ($d=="Wed")
      echo of_get_option('wednesday', 'no entry');
    elseif ($d=="Thu")
      echo of_get_option('thursday', 'no entry');
    elseif ($d=="Fri")
      echo of_get_option('friday', 'no entry');
    elseif ($d=="Sat")
      echo of_get_option('saturday', 'no entry');
    elseif ($d=="Sun")
      echo of_get_option('sunday', 'no entry');
    else
      echo "Have a nice day!";
?>
```

Comment: No the nested tags are and returning the value on their own, but when put in to the day of the week array it breaks.

Comment: Ah!Guess I didn't need those php tags. Thanks dude.

Comment: I noticed two downvotes on this. Because I stayed ontopic and helped him instead of delivering advices how to write more elegant code, I guess. This brings me closer to the Unsung Hero badge.

Answer (score 6):

In your `if/else` you dont need the `else` at all. Have a look at the [manual for `date`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). The only way `date` will return `false` is when you pass in a non-numeric timestamp for the second argument. You are not doing that, so `date` will return one of the days anyways.

But, instead of using `if/else` or `switch/case` (which would be the same), why dont you just use

```
echo of_get_option(strtolower(date('l')), 'no entry');
```

Calling `date` with `l` will give you the name of the day. `strtolower` will make it all lowercase. That mapping you are doing there is superfluous. The single line above is equivalent to the entire snippet you show in your question.

On a sidenote, what kind of function name is `of_get_option`? What is `of`? Does it stand for office? And if it does, why is that a function rather than a method on an `Office` object? After all, you said you are using objects. And why does it say `get_option` when its supposed to *display office hours*? Shouldn't the name rather be `getOfficeHoursOnDay($day)` or even better, `displayOfficeHoursOnDay($listRenderer, $day)`. Try to make your code more expressive and readable and try to move responsibilites where they belong.

Comment: `date('L')` should be enough, it will give the lowercase version (already +1d)

Comment: @baz no. the hint lowercase 'L' in the manual is just to indicate that it's actually an l (lowercase L) and not an I (uppercase i) or a 1 (one). Using `L` will tell you whether it's a leap year.

Comment: Haha, I'm way too drunk today :D. Sorry for bothering then :).

Answer (score 2):

You certainly don't need to open other PHP tags if one is already open.

---

It's nice that a solution has been found, but let me post a version that is a bit more readable and there is no unnecessary repetition. It uses an array for mapping purposes.

```
<?php
    $d=date("D");
    $mapping=array(
        "Mon" => "monday",
        "Tue" => "tuesday",
        "Wed" => "wednesday",
        ...
    );

    if (array_key_exists($d, $mapping)) {
        echo of_get_option($mapping[$d], 'no entry');
    }
    else {
        echo "Have a nice day!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: If the downvoter explained his problem, I'd be happy to improve my answer.

Comment: I guess the problem is that all that mapping isnt needed at all

Comment: @Gordon Hm, yes, I upvoted your answer, it is certainly the best way (I still leave my answer here, it is certainly better practice than a dozen ifs/switch). Seems like the situation is only that everyone uses their downvotes in a different way, and it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using switch and remove extra  tags from code, for example

```
$d=date("D");
switch ($d) {
case "Mon":
echo of_get_option('monday', 'no entry');
break;
case "Tue":
echo of_get_option('tuesday', 'no entry');
break;
default:
echo "Have a nice day!";
}
```

Comment: This would have been accomplished the same. Downvote unnecessary.

Comment: how is that better than using if/else?

Comment: it's up to you, you can use switch or if/else. I'd prefer switch here because it more compact

Comment: Whether the OP uses if/else or switch/case makes no difference whatsoever. you are effectively telling him to rewrite his code for no benefit. its not even more compact as you claim because those breaks will make the whole thing just longer. And the entire conditional construct is unneeded anyway.

Comment: Ok, but in my snippet not only "if" changed to "switch". Also I removed extra tags, so the whole thing will work. I haven't explained this, it's my bad, because i think it's clear enough. Added extra explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting away from using strings at all.  Date returns localized strings depensing upon locale settings.  So you wind up with a magic string that isn't so magic.

Instead, use the numeric day of week:

```
 of_get_option(date('w'));
```

You will of course need to change the function to accept it.  But its easier to understand, more portable, and IMHO cleaner...